# Mongodb setup replica set in parallel on same server

Tags: replication, mongodb, restore

I would like to know how to proceed to deploy a mongodb replica set environment on my servers where, in turn, other mongodb instances are already running, the following happens:

I have a mongodb replica set server running and I want to set up another replica set environment in parallel.
Clone the current server (it's a vm) and create two clones, but to avoid testing the current one that is running, copy the mongo data directory and create another configuration file that points to that data directory, but when I start that instance and try to display information I get the following error:

```
[root@mongodb01 ~]# mongo --port 27057
MongoDB shell version v4.4.23
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27057/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("c24b6c05-e921-47cb-8728-7fbff89fd085") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.23
---
MongoDB Enterprise > show dbs
uncaught exception: Error: listDatabases failed:{
        "topologyVersion" : {
                "processId" : ObjectId("64e609d41e461c651918c0df"),
                "counter" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false",
        "code" : 13435,
        "codeName" : "NotPrimaryNoSecondaryOk"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs/<@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147:19
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:99:12
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:937:13
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:819:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
MongoDB Enterprise >
```

It still keeps the replica configuration of the instance cloned:

```
MongoDB Enterprise > rs.conf()
{
        "_id" : "myreplicaset01",
        "version" : 3,
        "term" : 12,
        "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
        "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : true,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "mongodb01.lab.lo:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "mongodb02.lab.lo:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "mongodb03.lab.lo:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
        "settings" : {
                "chainingAllowed" : true,
                "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
                "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
                "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
                "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
                "getLastErrorModes" : {

                },
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                },
                "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("64dc2d0cd950391d47b7972e")
        }
}
```

This is my configuration of the current instance that is running (the highlights):

```
[root@mongodb01 ~]# cat /etc/mongod.conf
...
  path: /mongodb1/mongod.log
dbPath: /mongodb1
net:
   port: 27017
replication:
   replSetName: "myrepliset01"
```

This is my configuration of the current instance that is running (the highlights):

```
[root@mongodb01 ~]# cat /etc/mongodtest.conf
   path: /mongodb_test1/mongod.log
   dbPath: /mongodb_test1
net:
   port: 27057
replication:
   replSetName: "myreplicasettest"
```

Could you give me any advice or suggestion on how to solve this problem? the idea is to have a parallel replica set environment where to test,
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you are building really, it's not recommended to have more than one mongod at a single machine. But if you try to run more than one mongod process on one machine, all resources that mongods are using, must be unique. Those processes can't share anything.

Comment: You can take a copy from `dbPath` and follow [Restore a Replica Set from MongoDB Backups](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/)